# How can I shift the letters of a string in C++ 17?

Tags: c++, c++17

For example, shifting from 'Hi' to 'Jk' by shifting forward in the alphabet by two letters.

So far, I have tried this:

```
string myString = 'Hello';
string shifted = myString + 2;
cout << shifted << endl;
```

Which works for chars, but won't do anything for strings. Is there anything else that will work?

Comment: Hint: `myString[0]`

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you shift 'Z' by 2?

Comment: This doesn't work for `char` either, it will shift the pointer by 2. In `C` you would use a loop as well.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It will work for a `char`, but not a `char*`. You are correct you would use a loop for a C-string too.

Comment: Don't use *single quotes* for strings, use *double quotes*. `"Hello"` rather than `'Hello'`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::transform`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello");
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return c + 2; });

    // if you don't want to flush stdout, you may use "\n" instead of "\n"
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

How this works is it operates using a callback on each character, and transforms the string in-place.

The callback merely adds 2 to the unsigned character:

```
[](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return c + 2; }
```

The rest is just:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), callback);
```

Simple, extensible, and easy-to-read.

Comment: Using `std::transform` is the only correct answer. One could also argue for handling cases such as ofsetting the very end of the alphabet (for example `'z' + 2`), but the OP did not mention this case

Comment: @Fureeish A range based loop is another correct answer. More concise and easier to read too.

Comment: @juanchopanza I disagree with ranged-based for begin better or even equal to `std::transform` in this case. This algorithm was specifically designed to handle such cases. The plain usage of `std::transform` already suggests the intention, while ranged-based for does not. I do agree that both can accomplish the task, but I believe that `std::transform` is simply superior here

Comment: @Fureeish Specifically designed before range based loops existed, and for a more general case.

Comment: @Fureeish Would you please elaborate your believes?

Comment: yea you can use it if performance isn't critical. But if it is your offer is nothing. If we're talkin about PC you should use smth like `_mm_add_epi8`

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop:

```
std::string myString = "Hello";
std::string shifted;

for (auto const &ch : myString)
    shifted += ch + 2;

std::cout << shifted << '\n';
```

If you want to shift only letters and have them wrap around if a shifted value would be `>'Z'` or `>'z'`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype> // std::islower(), std::isupper()

// ...

for (auto const &ch : myString) {
    if (std::islower(static_cast<char unsigned>(ch)))  // *)
        shifted += 'a' + (ch - 'a' + shift) % ('z' - 'a' + 1);

    if (std::isupper(static_cast<char unsigned>(ch)))
        shifted += 'A' + (ch - 'A' + shift) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
}
```

*) Don't feed those functions negative values.

Comment: cout << '\n' is not a good idea, use std::endl instead, endl contains a flush, so that stuff actually gets printed right away

Comment: @jakub_d Please don't use `endl`, or recommend `endl`, unless a flush is very explicitly required. `endl` is very expensive.

Comment: @jakub_d Show me one platform where `stdout` isn't line-buffered.

Comment: @Swordfish Unix, when `stdout` isn't a terminal

Comment: @Barry um. Yes. I assumed `stdout` being connected to a terminal.

Comment: @Swordfish I'm not sure why you would assume that. It's pretty common to pipe one process to a file or a different process.

Comment: @Barry Because using an explicit flush on a fully buffered filestream is even more pointless than when writing to a terminal.

Comment: 'very expensive' is overselling it. You are more likely to run into problems because of not flushing (missing data after a crash, "why is my stuff not printing?") than because you vere flushing too often.

Comment: @jakub_d Fact is that a flush is more expensive than no flush. The bs of teaching beginners to use `std::endl` for a newline is just that: bs. If you \*really\* want a flush then be explicit and write what you want: `std::flush`.